# How can I improve my Trie implementation in terms of initialization?

Tags: python, optimization, data-structures, trie

I'm trying to read in from a huge list of words and store them in a way that allows me to make quick retrievals later on. I first thought of using a trie and I'll admit my implementation is  naive, it's basically nested hash tables with each key being a different letter. Right now it takes forever to insert a word into the trie (running this program takes 20+ seconds), and I was wondering if anyone had any ideas as to what I could do to improve my insertion? This isn't for homework.

```
import string
import time

class Trie:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode()

    def insert_word(self, word):
        current_node = self.root
        for letter in word:
            trie_node = current_node.get_node(letter)
            current_node = trie_node

class TrieNode:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def get_node(self, letter):
        if letter in self.data:
            return self.data[letter]
        else:
            new_trie_node = TrieNode()
            self.data[letter] = new_trie_node
            return new_trie_node

def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    trie = Trie()

    with open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r') as dictionary:
        word_list = dictionary.read()
    word_list = word_list.split("\n")

    for word in word_list:
        trie.insert_word(word.lower())

    print time.time() - start_time, "seconds"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I assume `addWord` should be `insert_word`?

Comment: ah, yes, sorry about that. Not sure how that didn't get changed :\

Comment: How big is your list of words?

Comment: As you can see, it's fetching the file from /usr/share/dict/words. I put a len(word_list) and it has 234937 (I think unique?) words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is utterly pointless working on speeding up your trie initialisation before you have considered whether your search facility is working or not.**

In the code that @unutbu referred to, why do you imagine it is mucking about with `{'end':False}` and `pt['end']=True` ?

Here is some test data for you:

```
words_to_insert = ['foo', 'foobar']
queries_expecting_true = words_to_insert
queries_expecting_false = "fo foe foob food foobare".split()
```

And here's another thought: You give no indication that you want anything more than the ability to determine whether a query word is present or not. If that is correct, you should consider benchmarking your DIY trie against a built-in `set`. Criteria: load speed (consider doing this from a pickle), query speed, and memory usage.

If you do want more retrieved than a `bool`, then substitute `dict` for `set` and re-read this answer.

If you do want to search for words in an input string, then you could consider the code referenced by @unutbu, with bugs fixed and some speedups in the `find` function (evaluate `len(input)` only once, use `xrange` instead of `range` (Python 2.x)) and the unnecessary `TERMINAL: False` entries removed:

```
TERMINAL = None # Marks the end of a word

def build(words, trie=None): # bugs fixed
    if trie is None:
        trie = {}
    for word in words:
        if not word: continue # bug fixed
        pt = trie # bug fixed
        for ch in word:
            pt = pt.setdefault(ch, {})
        pt[TERMINAL] = True
    return trie

def find(input, trie):
    len_input = len(input)
    results = []
    for i in xrange(len_input):
        pt = trie
        for j in xrange(i, len_input + 1):
            if TERMINAL in pt:
                results.append(input[i:j])
            if j >= len_input or input[j] not in pt:
                break
            pt = pt[input[j]]
    return results
```

or you could look at [Danny Yoo's fast implementation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ahocorasick/0.9) of the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm).

Answer (score -1):

There is an alternate implementation of Trie [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130134/python-regex-matching-a-word-list/4130371#4130371).

Compare `Trie.insert_word` to `build`:

```
def build(words,trie={'end':False}):
    '''
    build builds a trie in O(M*L) time, where
        M = len(words)
        L = max(map(len,words))
    '''
    for word in words:
        pt=trie
        for letter in word:
            pt=pt.setdefault(letter, {'end':False})
        pt['end']=True
    return trie
```

With `Trie`, for each `letter` in `word`, `insert_word` calls `current_node.get_node(letter)`. This method has an `if` and `else` block, and must instantiate a new `TrieNode` whenever the `else` block is reached, and a new key-value pair is then inserted into the `self.data` dict.

With `build`, the trie itself is just a dict. For each `letter` in `word`, there is simply one call to `pt.setdefault(...)`. `dict` methods are implemented in C and are faster than implementing similar code in Python.

`timeit` shows about a 2x speed difference (in favor of `build`):

```
def alt_main():
    with open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r') as dictionary:
        word_list = dictionary.read()
    word_list = word_list.split("\n")
    return build(word_list)


% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.main()'
10 loops, best of 3: 1.16 sec per loop

% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.alt_main()'
10 loops, best of 3: 571 msec per loop
```

Comment: -1: (a) You fixed some of the errors in the referenced `build` function without mentioning that you fixed them. (b) You didn't fix the `arg=mutable_object` problem.